# SSL/TLS change cipher spec

Tags: ssl, cryptography, protocols, handshake

When the Client sends the change cipher spec message before the handshake is finished, does he send it encrypted with the new key or with the public key of the server?

So, for example:

```
cipher suite= TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC
```

Does the Client send the change cipher spec message encrypted with RSA and the PU of the Server or does he send it with AES and the master_key?

Comment: I think this kind of question is off-topic here but on-topic at [security.se]. Anyway, the ChangeCipherSpec is not encrypted at all. Finished (following ChangeCipherSpec) is the first message encrypted. And whatever you are trying to suggest with your *"cipher suite= TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC"* it has nothing to do with ChangeCipherSpec since this message is not used to set which cipher gets used at all.

Comment: Thanks for your help :) 
i gave this example with the cipher suite, bc i thought the message would be encrypted.

Comment: Things change with TLS 1.3, but since you are not specifying which version of TLS you talk above, the previous is correct for TLS ⩽ 1.2